# Direct Sum properties in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

" If E, F and G are three subspaces of a vector space V such that E⊕F = E⊕G then F = G. "

**Is this statement true or false?**

(My first intuition to say that this statement is false. But I was wondering, since we have E⊕F and E⊕G does that necessarily mean that E⊕F = E⊕G = V?
Like does the direct sum of any 2 subspaces always sum of to the entirety of the vector space V simply by the very definition that they direct sums?

so basically is this true?
if E ∩ F = {0} and E and F are both subspaces of vector space V, does that necessarily implies that E⊕F=V 
(my intuition tells me no but I am a bit confused.

Thanks in advance...)

Comment: The initial claim is false. For your last question choose $E = F = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no. Take the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then $\mathbb{R}^2 = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}\oplus \operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\} = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\}\oplus \operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$

but $\operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\}\neq \operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}.$

It is also not true that the direct sum of two spaces is equal to the entire space. Indeed, take any vector space of dimension $d \geq 1$. Then

$$\{0\}= \{0\} \oplus \{0\}$$

is not equal to the entire space.

A less trivial example:

$$\operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0)\}\oplus \operatorname{span}\{(0,1,0)\} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \{0\} \neq \mathbb{R}^3$$

Answer (score 0):

For a finite dimensional space, if $E\cap F=\{0\}$, $E\oplus F=V$ if and only if $\dim E+\dim F=\dim V$.

On the other hand, a proper subspace has an infinite number of complementary subspaces. For instance, in $K^2$ ($K$ is the base field), the subspace generated by a vector $u$ and the subspace generated by *any* vector $v$ non-collinear with $u$ is a complementary subspace. In particular, if $v$ and $v'$ are non-collinear such vectors, the generated  subspaces are not identical, but complementary.

Comment: so does that mean that in K^n (where K is the base field), there can only be n complementary subspaces of dimension 1?

Comment: and also is a subspace also technically a vector space as well?

Comment: Yes, a subspace is also a vector space. The most natural definition of subspace is the following: let $V$ be a vector space. Then $W$ is a subset of $V$ if $W$ is a vector space with the addition and scalar multiplication inherited by $V$.

Comment: thanks it all makes sense now... that is why all subspaces need the 0 vector as well! my goodness thanks

Comment: I meant subspace in the above. Not subset.